# SSOCR Running on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, ocr

I'm quite new in OCR, trying out this software -ssocr, but cannot get it running. Anyone tried this before?

I'm downloading the master file from [github](https://github.com/mkirchstein/SSOCR), but keep getting cannot execute binary file: Exec format error. I already installed the 32-bit package of libproxychains3, still to no avail

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install libimlib2-dev
wget http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/ssocr-2.14.1.tar.bz2
bzip2 -d ssocr-2.14.1.tar.bz2
tar xvf ssocr-2.14.1.tar
cd ssocr-2.14.1/
make
```

Run SSOCR

> ./ssocr -T six_digits.png

Please see details from [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=57727).